# How to use handler generator in Vue event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

All:

I wonder how can I run event handler generator function on event handler, for example:

```
<button @click="buildHandler()">Click</button>

function buildHandler(){
    return function(){
        alert("button clicked")
    }
}
```

Since Vue event handler accept both formats of event handlers with/without parenthesis, I wonder how to implement my handler builder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `()` in your template like :

```
  <button @click="buildHandler()();">Click</button>
```

in order to execute the returned function.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    buildHandler() {
     
      return function() {
        console.log("button clicked");
      };
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="buildHandler()();">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, so it is just simple as evaluate it?

Comment: sorry, i did not understand

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks so much.